# row index of "looked at" row case_when in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, case-when

I´m currently struggling with a coding task concerning the use of a case_when statement in R.
In general I would like to use the looked at row index of the case_when statement in the assignment part.

A short explanation to the data. I have large data.frame with a date-column, a geo layer-column and some numeric columns with numbers for the calculations.
The data.frame doesn't have any sorting and not for every point in time all geo layers are necessarily in the data.frame. Sadly I can't provide a real data set due to legal issues.

The task at hand is to compute on the one hand simple mathematical operations for the same point in time on the other side to compute mathematical operations for different points in time for the same geo layer and numeric value.
The mathematical operations vary as dose the interval between the time points.

For instance I need to calculate a change rate to the last quarter and last year of the value:
((current_value - last_quarter_value) / current_value)*100

This is how I'd like to code it.

```
library(tidyverse)



test_dataframe <- data.frame(
  times = c(rep(as.Date("2021-03-01"),2),rep(as.Date("2020-12-01"),2)),
  geo_layer = rep(c("001001001", "001001002"),2),
  numeric_value_a = 1:4,
  numeric_value_b = 4:1,
  numeric_value_c = c(1,NA,3,1)
  
)


check_comparison_times <- unique(test_dataframe$times)


test_dataframe <- test_dataframe %>% 
  mutate(
    normale_calculation = case_when(
      !is.na(numeric_value_c) ~ (numeric_value_a + numeric_value_b) / numeric_value_c,
      TRUE ~ Inf
    ),
    time_comparison = case_when(
      is.na(numeric_value_c) ~ Inf,
      (times - months(3)) %in% check_comparison_times ~ test_dataframe[
        which(
          test_dataframe[,"times"] == 
            (test_dataframe[row_index_of_current_looked_at_row, "times"] - months(3)) &
            test_dataframe[,"geo_layer"] == 
            test_dataframe[row_index_of_current_looked_at_row, "geo_layer"]
        )
        ,"numeric_value_c"] - test_dataframe[row_index_of_current_looked_at_row, "numeric_value_c"],
      TRUE ~ -Inf
    )
  )
```

With this desired outcome:

```
       times geo_layer numeric_value_a numeric_value_b numeric_value_c normal_calculation time_comparison
1 2021-03-01 001001001               1               4               1           5.000000               2
2 2021-03-01 001001002               2               3              NA                Inf             Inf
3 2020-12-01 001001001               3               2               3           1.666667            -Inf
4 2020-12-01 001001002               4               1               1           5.000000            -Inf
```

Currently I solve the problem with a triple loop in which I first pair the Values for time then for geo_layer and then execute the mathematical operation.
Since my Data-Set is much much lager than that this. This solution is every in efficient.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you describe what your desired operation is? I'm not sure I understand what's trying to be achieved since the example is not reproducible and the logic is a bit opaque. Though I think maybe the `lag` function could be useful?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I edited my Question and hope that this clarifies what I'd like to do.
I also thought of `lag` but since there is no pattern in the data I wasn't sure how to use it